# Somehow disabling /removing hover effect on page load, enabling on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Besides a lightbox, I also have a special galleri slider (showing 8 photos on the first slide and the rest on the second). In each side, there is an arrow (left and right). They both have an hover effect (standard:opacity 0.5. Hover: 1;) But when we are on slide 1, I dont want left arrow to have the hover effect. When I scroll to slide 2, I want the left arrow to get its hover effect and the right arrow should get the hover effect removed.

HTML:

```html
       <section id="galleriMain_container">
            <div id="galleriSectionTitle_container">
                <p class="galleriSectionTitle">GALLERI</p>
            </div>
            <div id="galleriMiddle_container">
            <div id="galleriNavArrowLeft_container">
                <svg class="navArrowLeft" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 451.847 451.847" style="enable-background:new 0 0 451.847 451.847;"
  xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <path d="M97.141,225.92c0-8.095,3.091-16.192,9.259-22.366L300.689,9.27c12.359-12.359,32.397-12.359,44.751,0
  c12.354,12.354,12.354,32.388,0,44.748L173.525,225.92l171.903,171.909c12.354,12.354,12.354,32.391,0,44.744
  c-12.354,12.365-32.386,12.365-44.745,0l-194.29-194.281C100.226,242.115,97.141,234.018,97.141,225.92z"/>
</g>
</svg>
            </div>
            <div id="galleriesContainer">...</div>
                                    <div id="galleriNavArrowRight_container">
                <svg class="navArrowRight" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 451.847 451.847" style="enable-background:new 0 0 451.847 451.847;"
  xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <path d="M97.141,225.92c0-8.095,3.091-16.192,9.259-22.366L300.689,9.27c12.359-12.359,32.397-12.359,44.751,0
  c12.354,12.354,12.354,32.388,0,44.748L173.525,225.92l171.903,171.909c12.354,12.354,12.354,32.391,0,44.744
  c-12.354,12.365-32.386,12.365-44.745,0l-194.29-194.281C100.226,242.115,97.141,234.018,97.141,225.92z"/>
</g>
</svg>
            </div>
```

jQuery:

```js
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navArrowRight').click(function (){
        $('#galleri_container').animate({'margin-left':'-105.5%'}, 1000);
    });
    $('.navArrowLeft').click(function (){
        $('#galleri_container').animate({'margin-left':'0'}, 1000);
    }); 
});
```

CSS:

```css
.navArrowLeft:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}
.navArrowRight:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}
.navArrowLeft, .navArrowRight{
    margin-top: 235px;
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: #4E4E4E;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}
.navArrowRight {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-filter: fliph;
    filter: fliph;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    float:left;
}
```

How can i do this with jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 added! :)

Comment: _"But when we are on slide 1"_ , can include examples slides at `html` ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you please include the jQuery code? Is this a plugin or whatsoever?

Comment: @D4V1D i can do that, but why do you need jquery, when the only jquery is the action when clicked?

Comment: We do need the jQuery code in order to know what we need to alter so we can match your requirements.

Comment: @D4V1D Here you go. jQuery Added. :)

Comment: Thanks for that. "*When I scroll to slide 2, I want [...] the right arrow should get the hover effect removed.*", why? If you have more than 2 slides, I don't see why you would want to remove effect of the right arrow as there are more slide to come.

Comment: I have 2 slides, each space for up to 8 images. Its basicly the container thats the slide. But, if im at the last slide, i cant use the right arrow (since there is no more slides), os i need to disable hover to show that.

Comment: `<div id="galleriesContainer">...</div>`: you're not showing us the full HTML code.

Comment: @D4V1D I didn't because, it fills over 100 lines. I can if you need though.

Comment: Could I see your js scripts section

Comment: @adminXVII I'll send you an email. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply toggle an hover class for your two arrow.

CSS:

```
.hover:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}
```

JS:

initial page load:

```
$(function(){
  $(".navArrowRight").addClass("hover");
});
```

on page change:

```
$(".navArrowRight").toggleClass("hover");
$(".navArrowLeft").toggleClass("hover");
```

with this, your code should look like:

```
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navArrowRight").addClass("hover");
    $('.navArrowRight').click(function (){
        $('#galleri_container').animate({'margin-left':'-105.5%'}, 1000);
        $(".navArrowRight").toggleClass("hover");
        $(".navArrowLeft").toggleClass("hover");
    });
    $('.navArrowLeft').click(function (){
        $('#galleri_container').animate({'margin-left':'0'}, 1000);
        $(".navArrowRight").toggleClass("hover");
        $(".navArrowLeft").toggleClass("hover");
    }); 
});
```

### UPDATE

This won't work with SVG since JQuery has a problem with it.

Use this instead with SVG tag:

```
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navArrowRight").attr("class","navArrowRight hover");
    $('.navArrowRight').click(function (){
        $('#galleri_container').animate({'margin-left':'-105.5%'}, 1000);
        toggle();
    });
    $('.navArrowLeft').click(function (){
        $('#galleri_container').animate({'margin-left':'0'}, 1000);
        toggle();
    }); 
});

function toggle(){
    if($(".navArrowRight").attr("class") == "navArrowRight"){
        $(".navArrowRight").attr("class","navArrowRight hover");
        $(".navArrowLeft").attr("class","navArrowLeft");
    } else {
        $(".navArrowRight").attr("class","navArrowRight");
        $(".navArrowLeft").attr("class","navArrowLeft hover");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in the code would you add `.addClass`?

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard on your initial setting function, i.e. in your body's onLoad or in the document.ready (`$(function(){...})`)

Comment: Which is when i click navArrowRight, then  addclass to nav areow left?

Comment: So you want to create ande function for it

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard are you reloading the page when you switch from left side to right side?

Comment: Or add it to the existing?

Comment: its down with margin left +/- width. So no

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard see my update, used your code

Comment: Now both arrows have no hover effect. I have no idea, why this is happening. IT's the same result i get overtime i try using jQuery on this. Hmm.

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard did you deleted the `:hover` css code for the normal `navArrow`s?

Comment: I did. Hmm, it's weird. Maybe it has something to do with the containers?

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard could you make a JSFiddle link so I could help you debugging?

Comment: Sure, let me finish this, and i'll add it

Comment: It is really reallt badly alignet in jsfiddle. I cant make it work ( the slides position and so) in fiddle.

Comment: is there somewhere i can contact you so we can fix the jsfiddle? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery, but you can also do it with CSS, using nested rules. If you create a CSS class for each slide, then you can have two sets of hover rules, something like:

```
.firstPane .navArrowLeft:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}
.secondPane .navArrowRight:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}
```

Add the classes "firstPane" and "secondPane" to the panes, respectively. That way, the hover effects are applied selectively, depending on which pane you have. You could also use jQuery .addClass() and removeClass(), depending on when each pane is focused

Comment: The css way, is not possible since the arrows is outside the sliders container. Would the jQuery be the only way then?

Comment: Yes. jQuery would be the way to go. I'll delete this. I recommend admin XVII's answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $arrowRight = $('.navArrowRight')
      , $arrowLeft = $('.navArrowLeft')
    ;

    $arrowRight.click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('#galleri_container').animate({'margin-left':'-105.5%'}, 1000, function() {
            $arrowLeft.removeClass('hover');
            $arrowRight.addClass('hover');

        });
    });
    $arrowLeft.click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('#galleri_container').animate({'margin-left':'0'}, 1000, function() {
            $arrowRight.removeClass('hover');
            $arrowLeft.addClass('hover');
        });
    }); 
});
```

For this given CSS:

```
.navArrowLeft.hover:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}
.navArrowRight.hover:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The hover effect disappears completely from the arrows.  It look's fine to me though, so I don't know what the problem is.